# "There was an error completing your request" when trying to make an Actions on Google project

Tags: actions-on-google

Whenever I try to make an Actions on Google project, I always end up with the error:

> There was an error completing your request

I don't have any extensions on my browser, and have made sure that I only have one account logged in when trying to make a project. It does end up making a project, but I can't choose what type of action I want to make (smart home action in my case). How would I fix this?

**Image of how what I put in to add the project**:

[image: Image of how what I put in to add the project]

**Image of the error I get**:

[image: Image of the error I get]

**Image of the project still showing up, but not having the option to turn it into a smart home action**:

[image: Image of the project still showing up, but not having the option to turn it into a smart home action]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your project is created, you can change or set the category by these steps:

- Click on the project
- Go to the "develop" section and click on "Actions". Here you would get this page:
  [Actions-on-google console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO0oU.png)
- Click on "Get started" and here you can choose the category of your action.
- Click on "Home automation" in your case.